# Virtualenv installed on Mac but can't be found

Tags: linux, bash, macos, pip, virtualenv

My MacBook didn't have virtualenv anywhere (because I uninstalled and `rm` everything).

I then installed virtualenv by

`sudo pip install virtualenv`

and I guess that installed virtualenv to /usr/local/bin because when I ran:

```
$ which virtualenv

/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

But when I want to use virtualenv to create a new virtual environment, I got this:

```
$ virtualenv venv

-bash: /usr/local/share/python/virtualenv: No such file or directory
```

Why is it looking for virtualenv in /usr/local/share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what's going on. virtualenv is installed:

```
    /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

But it's being referenced here:

/usr/local/share/python/virtualenv

You could add a link

```
    cd /usr/local/share/python/ && ln -s /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Comment: After tried all posible installs, the only one that worked for me on mac was:   sudo -H pip install virtualenv